# MQ Queue transaction not rolled back in a 2 phase transaction

Tags: java, ejb-2.x, 2phase-commit, bean-managed-transactions, ejb-timer

I have an EJB timer (EJB 2.1) which has bean managed transaction.

The timer code calls a business method which deals with 2 resources in a single transaction. One is database and other one is MQ queue server.

Application server used is Websphere Application Server 7 (WAS). In order to ensure consistency  across 2 resources (database and queue manager), we have enabled the option to support 2 phase commit in WAS. This is to ensure that in case of any exception during database operation, message posted in queue is rolled back along with database rollback and vice versa.

Below is the flow explained:

When timeout occurs in Timer code, startProcess() in DirectProcessor is called which is our business method. This method has a try block within which there is a method call to createPostXMLMessage() in the same class. This in turn has a call to another method postMessage() in class PostMsg.

The issue is when we encounter any database exception in createPostXMLMessage() method, the message posted earlier does not roll back although database part is successfully rolled back. Please help.

In ejb-jar.xml

```
<session id="Transmit">
    <ejb-name>Transmit</ejb-name>
    <home>com.TransmitHome</home>
    <remote>com.Transmit</remote>
    <ejb-class>com.TransmitBean</ejb-class>
    <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
    <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>       
</session>

public class TransmitBean implements javax.ejb.SessionBean, javax.ejb.TimedObject {
    public void ejbTimeout(Timer arg0) {
         ....

         new DIRECTProcessor().startProcess(mySessionCtx);

    }
}

public class DIRECTProcessor {

    public String startProcess(javax.ejb.SessionContext mySessionCtx) {

        ....

        UserTransaction ut= null;
        ut = mySessionCtx.getUserTransaction();

        try {
            ut.begin();
            createPostXMLMessage(interfaceObj, btch_id, dpId, errInd);
            ut.commit();
        } 

        catch (Exception e) {                      
             ut.rollback();
             ut=null;        
        }
    }

    public void createPostXMLMessage(ArrayList<InstrInterface> arr_instrObj, String batchId, String dpId,int errInd) throws Exception {
      ...

      PostMsg pm = new PostMsg();
      try {
            pm.postMessage( q_name, final_msg.toString());

           // database update operations using jdbc

      }

      catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;      
      }

    }
}

public class PostMsg {

    public String postMessage(String qName, String message) throws Exception {
        QueueConnectionFactory qcf = null;
        Queue que = null;
        QueueSession qSess = null;
        QueueConnection qConn = null;
        QueueSender qSender = null;
        que = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getQ(qName);

        try {
            qConn = (QueueConnection) qcf.createQueueConnection(
                    Constants.QCONN_USER, Constants.QCONN_PSWD);
            qSess = qConn.createQueueSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            qSender = qSess.createSender(que);

            TextMessage txt = qSess.createTextMessage();
            txt.setJMSDestination(que);
            txt.setText(message);
            qSender.send(txt);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            retval = Constants.ERROR;
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;

        } finally {

            closeQSender(qSender);
            closeQSession(qSess);
            closeQConn(qConn);
        }

        return retval;

    }

}
```